# Ошибка void value not ignored as it ought to be

Tags: c, структуры

Я пишу функцию для добавления элемента в список (со ссылками).

```
typedef struct _Node {
    void *value;
    struct _Node *next;
    struct _Node *prev; 
} Node;

typedef struct _queue {
    size_t size;
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
} queue;


void* create() {
    queue *tmp = (queue*) malloc(sizeof(queue));
    tmp->size = 0;
    tmp->head = tmp->tail = NULL;

    return tmp;
}



_Bool push(void *queue, void *entry){
    Node *tmp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        exit(1);
        return false;
    }

    tmp->value = entry;
    tmp->next = (*queue)->head;
    tmp->prev = NULL;
    if ((*queue)->head) {
        (*queue)->head->prev = tmp;
    }
    (*queue)->head = tmp;

    if ((*queue)->tail == NULL) {
        (*queue)->tail = tmp;
    }
    queue->size++;
    return true;
}
```

Ошибка в строке "tmp->next = (*queue)->head;"
[Error] void value not ignored as it ought to be

Comment: Почему `void *queue`, а не `queue *чтонибудь`? То же самое с `create()`, почему не возвращать `queue *`?

Comment: Ну так `queue` имеет тип `void *`, соответственно `*queue` имеет тип `void`. Почему вы пытаетесь применять оператор `->` к значеню типа `void`? Что это должно значить?

Comment: по условию у меня даны заголовки функций с тем что на вход и на выход void* create() , _Bool push(void *queue, void *entry). Нужно написать саму функцию. Подскажите как правильно написать функцию исходя из полученных данных .